# sqlsrv_query , php The incoming tabular data stream (TDS) remote procedure call (RPC) protocol stream is incorrect

Tags: php, sql-server, sqlsrv

I get an error when I try to update data in SQL Server with PHP.

Here is the PHP code:

```
$vip_cat = 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;

$sql = "UPDATE Warehouse SET Items = CAST( ? AS varbinary(1920)) WHERE AccountID = 'shono'";
$params = array($vip_cat);

$stmt = sqlsrv_query( $conn_ms, $sql, $params);
if( $stmt === false ) {
 die( print_r( sqlsrv_errors(), true));
}else{
  echo 'ok';
}
```

Here is my error:

> Array ( [0] => Array ( [0] => 42000 [SQLSTATE] => 42000 [1] => 8023
>   [code] => 8023 [2] => [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server][SQL
>   Server]The incoming tabular data stream (TDS) remote procedure call
>   (RPC) protocol stream is incorrect. Parameter 3 (""): The supplied
>   value is not a valid instance of data type float. Check the source
>   data for invalid values. An example of an invalid value is data of
>   numeric type with scale greater than precision. [message] =>
>   [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server][SQL Server]The incoming
>   tabular data stream (TDS) remote procedure call (RPC) protocol stream
>   is incorrect. Parameter 3 (""): The supplied value is not a valid
>   instance of data type float. Check the source data for invalid values.
>   An example of an invalid value is data of numeric type with scale
>   greater than precision. ) )

What I tried:

```
$sql = "UPDATE Warehouse SET Items = CAST( (?) AS varbinary(1920)) WHERE AccountID = 'shono'";
```

And:

```
$sql = "UPDATE Warehouse SET Items = CAST( $vip_cat AS varbinary(1920)),WarNum = (?) WHERE AccountID = 'shono'";
$params = array(1);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the problem

```
$sql = "UPDATE Warehouse SET Items = CAST( **?** AS varbinary(1920)) WHERE AccountID = 'shono'";
**$params = array($vip_cat);**

$stmt = sqlsrv_query( $conn_ms, $sql, **$params**);
```

We just need to remove $params from $stmt = sqlsrv_query( $conn_ms, $sql, **$params**);
and we'll get the correct code like this

```
$stmt = sqlsrv_query( $conn_ms, $sql);
```

Also here'll be the correct COMMAND for SQL

```
UPDATE Warehouse SET Items = CAST(
0x00..
AS varbinary(1920)) WHERE AccountID = 'shono'
```

Comment: This is a possible solution,but the approach using parameters should be your first option. `$vip_cat` should be a string and use `CONVERT` with the additional style parameter.

Comment: No, if u send $vip_cat as string , this will convert HEX to HEX again and you will get not 0x067F63D... but 0x646464